# Change NAs to interpolated flat bars

Tags: r, xts

If I have some OHLC data, with some NA rows, is there already a function in one of the R packages that will interpolate data?

`na.locf` has two cons:

1. It is flat, then a sudden jump
2. Used naively, it will repeat the whole of the last bar, with its high/lows

**UPDATE:** `na.approx` is superior to `na.locf` in the first respect, thanks Dirk, but I'm still searching for an existing function that is *bar-aware*. I.e. that will interpolate from the close of previous bar to the open of the next non-NA bar, and will create flat bars. Bonus points if it sets volume to zero!  (So, I suspect the answer to my question is going to be "No", and I'll roll-my-own... but I'll wait a bit longer.)

### ASIDE: na.approx vs. na.spline

Executive summary: `na.spline` is *imaginative*, use with care!

Here is some FX data (close prices only) with the original data in blue, and the `na.approx` joins shown in green:

[image]

Then here is the same data, but using `na.spline`:

[image]

Of particular concern is that na.spline has decided to create a new high!

Comment: Take a look at `zoo::na.spline`

Answer (score 4):

Besides `na.locf()`, there are already several other methods in package [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo):

- `na.aggregate()`
- `na.approx()`
- `na.fill()`
- `na.spline()`
- `na.trim()`

and `na.approx()` or `na.spline()` offer you interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The mice package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) may helps you.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I took a brief look, and I think it is `na.approx` on steroids :-) Do you know of any examples showing it applied to zoo or xts objects?

Comment: There are several imputation packages --- but do any of these reflect the _time-series_ aspect we want here?