# Add missing xts/zoo data with linear interpolation in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I do have problems with missing data, but I do not have NAs - otherwise would be easier to handle...

My data looks like this:

```
time, value
2012-11-30 10:28:00, 12.9
2012-11-30 10:29:00, 5.5
2012-11-30 10:30:00, 5.5
2012-11-30 10:31:00, 5.5
2012-11-30 10:32:00, 9
2012-11-30 10:35:00, 9
2012-11-30 10:36:00, 14.4
2012-11-30 10:38:00, 12.6
```

As you can see - there are missing some minute values - it is xts/zoo so I use as.POSIXct... to set the date as an index. How to add the missing timesteps to get a full ts? I want to fill the missing values with linear interpolation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Got one possible answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114834/interpolate-zoo-object-with-missing-dates?rq=1
does work with zoo - but afterwards I can go back to xts.

Still the problem with the "wrong" values - how to filter and set to NA?
Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897169/change-nas-to-interpolated-flat-bars

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `merge` your data with a vector with all dates. After that you can use `na.approx` to fill in the blanks (NA in this case).

```
data1 <-read.table(text="time, value
2012-11-30-10:28:00, 12.9
2012-11-30-10:29:00, 5.5
2012-11-30-10:30:00, 5.5
2012-11-30-10:31:00, 5.5
2012-11-30-10:32:00, 9
2012-11-30-10:35:00, 9
2012-11-30-10:36:00, 14.4
2012-11-30-10:38:00, 12.6", header = TRUE, sep=",", as.is=TRUE)
times.init <-as.POSIXct(strptime(data1[,1], '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'))
data2 <-zoo(data1[,2],times.init)
data3 <-merge(data2, zoo(, seq(min(times.init), max(times.init), "min")))
data4 <-na.approx(data3)
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [P Lapointe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042478/p-lapointe) for a cool answer. Also, if you also take advantage of the 'xout' argument in na.approx, you no longer need to do the merger:

```
data1 <-read.table(text="time, value
2012-11-30-10:28:00, 12.9
2012-11-30-10:29:00, 5.5
                   2012-11-30-10:30:00, 5.5
                   2012-11-30-10:31:00, 5.5
                   2012-11-30-10:32:00, 9
                   2012-11-30-10:35:00, 9
                   2012-11-30-10:36:00, 14.4
                   2012-11-30-10:38:00, 12.6", header = TRUE, sep=",", as.is=TRUE)
times.init <-as.POSIXct(strptime(data1[,1], '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'))
data2 <-zoo(data1[,2],times.init)
data2
data4 <- na.approx(object=data2, 
          xout=seq(min(times.init), max(times.init), "min"))
```