# Delete specific values in R with zoo/xts

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, missing-data

My other Question about "Add missing xts/zoo data with linear interpolation in R" you can find here [Add missing xts/zoo data with linear interpolation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011790/add-missing-xts-zoo-data-with-linear-interpolation-in-r) .

But in general there is one more problem with my data - I do have "wrong" values not making sense:

```
"2012-04-09 05:03:00",2
"2012-04-09 05:04:00",4
"2012-04-09 05:05:39",-10
"2012-04-09 05:09:00",0
"2012-04-09 05:10:00",1
```

So the replacement of missing dates works:

```
y <- merge(y, zoo(,seq(start(y),end(y),by="min")), all=TRUE)
y <- na.approx(y)
```

But as you can see the -10 makes no sense, and the value is not at min:sec with value 00. I need a solution like na.rm.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what do you want to do. But I guess you want to remove some outliers from xts object. If you want a solution like "na.rm", one idea is to replace non desired values by `NA` then you remove them using `na.omit`.

```
x <- read.zoo(text='
"2012-04-09 05:03:00",2
"2012-04-09 05:04:00",4
"2012-04-09 05:05:39",-10
"2012-04-09 05:09:00",0
"2012-04-09 05:10:00",1',sep=',',tz='')

x[x == -10] <- NA
na.omit(x)

                    x
2012-04-09 05:03:00 2
2012-04-09 05:04:00 4
2012-04-09 05:09:00 0
2012-04-09 05:10:00 1
```

**EDIT**

To get condition per date , you can look at index(x) and format it for example.

```
format(index(dat),'%S')
[1] "00" "00" "39" "00" "00"
```

But here I use built-in `.indexsec` ( see also .indexmin, .indexhour,..)

```
dat[.indexsec(dat) != 0]
2012-04-09 05:05:39 
                -10
```

Comment: Exactly what I mean - thank you! This solution is by looking for a specific value - is there also a possibility by date? Not having h:m:00 - for seconds?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to replace value that are below a threshold (0 in this case) with NA. You can run `na.approx` afterwards.

```
# read in
Lines <- '"2012-04-09 05:03:00",2
"2012-04-09 05:04:00",4
"2012-04-09 05:05:39",-10
"2012-04-09 05:09:00",0
"2012-04-09 05:10:00",1
'
data2 <- as.xts(read.zoo(text = Lines, sep = ",", tz = ""))

# perform calculation
data2[data2<0] <- NA
```