# Add missing dates with previous values in R - converting quarterly to daily data

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I am trying to convert quarterly data into daily data by adding the previous values on the missing dates. This data consists of financial ratios of different stocks. My data has a row label built from two columns: ticker and date. Since I have repetitive dates for each stock, I am not sure how to ignore the ticker and repopulate the missing dates with previous values.

Here is how a small sample of the data looks so far:

```
> df_new
                   de   eps      pe    ps    pb
APD 2015-09-30  1.373   1.6  21.463 2.772 3.784
APD 2015-12-31  1.325  1.68  21.284 2.893 3.805
APD 2016-03-31  1.411 -2.19  56.114 3.254 4.491
SWKS 2003-03-31 0.402 -0.04    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
SWKS 2003-06-30 0.397 -0.04  -2.289 1.518 0.929
SWKS 2003-09-30  0.62 -0.29  -2.799 2.046 1.877
SWKS 2003-12-31 0.643  0.03 -25.426 2.045 1.905
SWKS 2004-03-31 0.657 -0.06 -32.004 2.641 2.579
SWKS 2004-06-30 0.584  0.09  -37.18 1.825 1.782
SWKS 2004-09-30 0.555   0.1  65.806 1.881 1.962
SWKS 2004-12-31 0.525  0.09  45.823 1.777 1.912
```

And I want it to look like this (if weekly):

```
> df_new
                   de   eps      pe    ps    pb
APD 2015-09-30  1.373   1.6  21.463 2.772 3.784
APD 2015-10-01  1.373   1.6  21.463 2.772 3.784
APD 2015-10-02  1.373   1.6  21.463 2.772 3.784
APD 2015-10-03  1.373   1.6  21.463 2.772 3.784
... 
APD 2015-12-31  1.325  1.68  21.284 2.893 3.805
APD 2016-01-01  1.325  1.68  21.284 2.893 3.805
APD 2016-01-02  1.325  1.68  21.284 2.893 3.805
APD 2016-01-03  1.325  1.68  21.284 2.893 3.805
...
APD 2016-03-31  1.411 -2.19  56.114 3.254 4.491
APD 2016-04-01  1.411 -2.19  56.114 3.254 4.491
APD 2016-04-02  1.411 -2.19  56.114 3.254 4.491
APD 2016-04-03  1.411 -2.19  56.114 3.254 4.491
...
SWKS 2003-03-31 0.402 -0.04    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
SWKS 2003-04-01 0.402 -0.04    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
SWKS 2003-04-02 0.402 -0.04    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
SWKS 2003-04-03 0.402 -0.04    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
...
SWKS 2003-06-30 0.397 -0.04  -2.289 1.518 0.929
and so on...
```

I searched for answers and this link: [Add missing xts/zoo data with linear interpolation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011790/add-missing-xts-zoo-data-with-linear-interpolation-in-r) is somewhat close to what I want. Though I am not sure what to do with ticker symbol.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `by` to apply the anonymous function shown to each symbol's rows.  That function produces a grid `g` of dates and merges it with the original rows of the data frame applying `na.locf` to fill in NA values.  Finally we use `do.call("rbind", ...)` to put the `"by"` object produced back together.

```
library(zoo) # na.locf

df <- do.call("rbind", by(df_new, df_new$symbol, function(x) {
  rng <- range(x$date, na.rm = TRUE)
  g <- data.frame(date = seq(rng[1], rng[2], "day"))
  na.locf(merge(x, g, all = TRUE))
}))
```

**Note:** The input `df_new` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
APD 2015-09-30  1.373   1.6  21.463 2.772 3.784
APD 2015-12-31  1.325  1.68  21.284 2.893 3.805
APD 2016-03-31  1.411 -2.19  56.114 3.254 4.491
SWKS 2003-03-31 0.402 -0.04    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
SWKS 2003-06-30 0.397 -0.04  -2.289 1.518 0.929
SWKS 2003-09-30  0.62 -0.29  -2.799 2.046 1.877
SWKS 2003-12-31 0.643  0.03 -25.426 2.045 1.905
SWKS 2004-03-31 0.657 -0.06 -32.004 2.641 2.579
SWKS 2004-06-30 0.584  0.09  -37.18 1.825 1.782
SWKS 2004-09-30 0.555   0.1  65.806 1.881 1.962
SWKS 2004-12-31 0.525  0.09  45.823 1.777 1.912"
df_new <- read.table(text = Lines, 
   col.names = c("symbol", "date", "de", "eps", "pe", "ps", "pb"))
df_new$date <- as.Date(df_new$date)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response G. Grothendieck!!  I was wondering how to do the same thing you are doing but with the row name (label) being the ticker and symbol all together since my dataframe is being saved like that already (ex. rowname[1,1] is APD 2015-09-30). I am consolidating various databases into a single one but have different periodicity in all of them so I am using the row name as label to being identified by each of the existing databases.

Comment: @marya You probably want `rownames(df) <- paste(df$symbol, df$date)`, but there is no such thing as a rownames index operation of `[1, 1]` ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment FXQuantTrader! I was just trying to give an example of the rowname on first row and somehow wrote that but you are right! not such thing so my bad! (First time in this forum :) ..) My databases are already consolidated that way with the rownames being symbol and date using the paste function, I was actually asking how to get the function G. Grothendieck wrote above but considering the rownames being like this. I guess I can use separate() to use function above then or pass this function before the paste(). Thanks again!!! I really appreciate the help!